# What is the in-place/Out-of-place builds

Tags: build, build-process, cmake

As in the title the questions is what is the difference between (in-place/Out-of-place builds)?

Comment: @David i edited the question to what is the difference between (in-place/Out-of-place builds)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An *in-place* build generates the various compiled files (`.o`/`.obj` files, executables, &c.) in the same directory as the source tree.

An *out-of-place* build generates them in some directory that is not the source directory. This means that you can have several out-of-place builds that all point back to the same source tree, which is not possible once you have an in-place build.

See also: [The CMake FAQ](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#What_is_an_.22out-of-source.22_build.3F).

Comment: It is also easier to cleanup a build when having it *out-of-place*.